# Can't find Raspberry PI IP

Tags: raspbian, ssh, ethernet

I bought Raspberry PI 4B few days ago.

I downloaded Raspbian buster lite and placed it on an SD-card, placed ssh with no extension so that I can access it thorugh ssh. I put the prepared sdcard into the raspberry pi, connected to the power, and connected my PC with it via ethernet cable.

I can see raspberry ethernet diodes blinking so I think everything's ok but scanning with Advanced IP Scanner and nmap doesn't show raspberry. How can I connect to raspberry  and what could cause this problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: What subnet do you scan? What exactly is the command do you use with `nmap`?

Comment: `connected my PC with it via ethernet cable` - is either side running DHCP "server"?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is much simpler than finding the IP address.

Raspian supports mDNS and that will make the process to find your Raspberry Pi easy as...

Use `raspberrypi.local` instead of the IP address!

and if you change the "hostname" on your Raspberry Pi the mDNS address will be `yourhostname.local`

And for the rest I agree with @Milliways answer.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the root drive on the SD card and open `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` with a text editor. Enter the network settings as shown in the examples there. Save the file and boot up the pie. Also dont Forget to set a static IP on you PC.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague, but from the description it is unlikely to have an IP Address, although it may have a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). What you can do with this is limited, and depends on the connected computer.

**NOTE** the Pi is designed to connect to a router - make life easier for yourself by doing so.

If you want to connect directly you need to setup the Pi with a terminal and keyboard.
 See the following
[How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
[How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)